# How to get specific pair from the following api response

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, string-formatting

The response I receive from api is in the below format:

```
"NetRange: 185.0.0.0 - 185.255.255.255 CIDR: 185.0.0.0/8 NetName: RIPE-185 NetHandle: NET-185-0-0-0-1 Parent: () NetType: Allocated to RIPE NCC OriginAS: Organization: RIPE Network Coordination Centre (RIPE) RegDate: 2011-01-04 Updated: 2011-02-08 Comment: These addresses have been further assigned to users in Comment: the RIPE NCC region. Contact information can be found in Comment: the RIPE database at http://www.ripe.net/whois Ref: https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/185.0.0.0 ResourceLink: https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html ResourceLink: whois.ripe.net **OrgName: RIPE Network Coordination Centre** OrgId: RIPE Address: P.O. Box 10096 City: Amsterdam StateProv: PostalCode: 1001EB Country: NL RegDate: Updated: 2013-07-29 Ref: https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/RIPE ReferralServe "
```

But I only need the value pair as highlighted. How exactly the formatting should be done for the same in python?
I'm using python 3.

Comment: I only need "OrgName: RIPE Network Coordination Centre" from the above string.

Comment: What did you try so far? Any code?

Comment: So the `**` in the string is text that you have added?

Comment: What regex have you used so far? Also, since the data is kind of key-value and an API response, then I would strongly recommend to change the API contract and use a schema based or json or protobuff etc.

Comment: @FredrikHedman I have added ** to the text because I only want that or some other key-value pair. The ** is not in the api response.

Comment: I haven't used regex till now. I tried to get the data using: dict = res = {sub.split(":")[13]: sub.split(":")[14] for sub in whotemp[1:-1].split(", ")} but i did'nt work.

Comment: So your question is really how to parse the response string into key-value pairs,, or?

Comment: @FredrikHedman yes...the question is how to parse the key-value pairs from this response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) regular expression module:

```
import re

#assume that resp is response from API
resp = "NetRange: 185.0.0.0 - 185.255.255.255 CIDR: 185.0.0.0/8 NetName: RIPE-185 NetHandle: NET-185-0-0-0-1 Parent: () NetType: Allocated to RIPE NCC OriginAS: Organization: RIPE Network Coordination Centre (RIPE) RegDate: 2011-01-04 Updated: 2011-02-08 Comment: These addresses have been further assigned to users in Comment: the RIPE NCC region. Contact information can be found in Comment: the RIPE database at http://www.ripe.net/whois Ref: https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/185.0.0.0 ResourceLink: https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html ResourceLink: whois.ripe.net OrgName: RIPE Network Coordination Centre OrgId: RIPE Address: P.O. Box 10096 City: Amsterdam StateProv: PostalCode: 1001EB Country: NL RegDate: Updated: 2013-07-29 Ref: https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/RIPE ReferralServe "

regex = r"OrgName:\s(.+?)\sOrgId"
orgName = re.findall(regex, resp)[0]
print(orgName) #RIPE Network Coordination Centre
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple parser of the data you are getting:

```
def parse_reply(data):
    tmp = []
    result = {}
    kvdata = data.split()
    key = kvdata[0]
    for e in kvdata[1:]:
        if e.endswith(':'):
            result[key] = " ".join(tmp)
            key = e[:-1]
            tmp.clear()
        else:
            tmp.append(e)
    return result


rep = parse_reply(data)
print(rep['OrgName'])
```